# How to fix "the code enters to else part additionally" while loop problem in this code?

Tags: java, database, eclipse

I am trying to print username and password but, the code enters else part twice.

I added print functions for conditions.

1. In the case of username and password matched, I took `"Matched!"` and `"Invalid username or password!"` messages.
2. In case of the only username matched, I took `"Username!"` and `"Invalid username or password!"` messages.
3. In case of the only password matched, I took `"Password"` and `"Invalid username or password!"` messages.
4. In case of nothing matched, I got `"Invalid username or password!"` message twice.

Below is the code

```
Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `Employee`");
while(resultSet.next()) {
    if(resultSet.getString("username").matches(textField_1.getText()) && resultSet.getString("password").matches(textField_2.getText())) {
        System.out.println("Matched!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid username or password!");
    }
}
```

The result suppose to be "Matched!" for valid password and username.
The result suppose to be "Invalid username or password!" for invalid username or password.

Comment: With this query you are looping through all the employees, not the one with a specific user and passwords. Also for comparing Strings use equals(), matches uses regular expressions.

Comment: What is your use case ? If Matched what you want to do ? do you want to iterate further or break the while loop ?

Comment: I want to create a new frame after username and password that will be entered by me in text fields matches in the Employee table.

Comment: So you just missed the break statement in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `Employee`");
boolean check = false;
while(resultSet.next()){ 
    if(resultSet.getString("username").matches(textField_1.getText()) && resultSet.getString("password").matches(textField_2.getText())){ 
        System.out.println("Matched!");
        check = true;
        break;
    }

}
if (check == false){

      System.out.println("Invalid username or password!");
}
```

Now the while loop will search for the right username and password if not will print Invalid.

Answer (score 0):

You’re basically getting all the employees details storing it to resultSet but then you are iterating through each one of them. If you had 3 sets of usernames and passwords and only one matches then you will get

```
Matched!
Invalid
Invalid
```

Instead you may want to just check one username and password? Not sure exactly what you’re looking for. Also when you do compare the usernames and passwords use .equals().

**EDIT**

Edit to answer above, use `.equals()` instead of `.matches()`.

```
Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();

ResultSet resultSet = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM `Employee`");

boolean check = false;

while(resultSet.next()){ 

    if(resultSet.getString("username").equals(textField_1.getText()) && 
       resultSet.getString("password").equals(textField_2.getText()))
    { 

        System.out.println("Matched!");
        check = true;
        break;

    }

}

if (check == false){

      System.out.println("Invalid username or password!");
}
```

Comment: I want to compare username and password in my database table and text fields. In my table, there are three entries. For instances, I enter 1234 for the password and jane for the username. After that, I want to check these entries 1234 and jane in my database table. If there is an existing user, I will create a new frame.

Comment: Yes that's fine, I made an edit with the correct way you should do.